# Querying solr *:* doesnt return values where numDocs are present

Tags: solr

When I performing query like `"*:*"`  in `http://localhost:8983/solr/admin` doesnt return any response(no documents were returned].
But when I checked the count of documents indexed were 300 in `http://localhost:8983/solr/admin/stats.jsp.` 
But in query string if i give title of the document, it returns the response.
1) How to check the log for solr?
2) Why doesnt it returns all the document?

Comment: What does the actual query string look like?

Comment: http://localhost:8983/solr/select/?q=cardnumber&version=2.2&start=0&rows=10&indent=on returns the document. But when i give "*:*" http://localhost:8983/solr/select/?q=*%3A*&version=2.2&start=0&rows=10&indent=on , it doestnt return any documents.

Comment: And what query parser is in effect? (although dismax and standard should both return documents for `*:*`)

Comment: Dismax parser. apachesolr-version 3.5.0

Comment: You cannot use the dismax parser - it will not understand `*:*` as for all documents. Use the standard query parser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The DisMax query parser does not understand `*:*` as the special shortcut to return all documents. Use the standard query parser (by either leaving out the `defType` parameter or using `defType=lucene`).

Comment: I removed the defType in solrconfig.xml.After removing that defType in solrconfig.xml,if i give `field_name:*` in query string,it returns response.But doesnt returns any response for `*:*`.By refering to this site [link]https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/The+Standard+Query+Parser , solr-3.5 -so query parser would be DisMax.How to confirm it whether it is running on standard query parser?.

Comment: Part of the output returned from Solr is the parsed parameters for the request. The defType should be included there if it has been changed from the default. Running with debugQuery will give you the information anyway, look for something like `"QParser": "LuceneQParser"` (in the JSON output format, the XML should be similar).

Comment: i tried and it showed `"QParser": "LuceneQParser"`.With debugmode enabled `*:*` it returns documents. thanks for ur help :)

Comment: Hi i tried the above solution and i also checked the response, it is showing "QParser": "LuceneQParser"  but still i m not getting documents. any solutions

Comment: @deenbandhu Ask a separate question and provide the relevant details there (query, which document you expected to be returned, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

Are you querying an actual collection? /solr/admin usually takes you to the admin UI. Try running the query on

```
/solr/{{collection}}/select?q=*:*
```

Answer (score -1):

Not sure how your actual query looks like. but Try With "%:%".

Comment: Tried with "%:%" and `"*:*"`. It does nt return any response

Comment: why don't you paste your query too in your question for others to understand better.

Comment: In http://localhost:8983/solr/admin this page, in query string when i gave `*:*` does not return any documents. Instead of giving `*:*`,if i give strings like test,document, it returns the response.`*:* have to return all the document but in my case it returns nothing.